# Latest webdriver manager not working with current framework code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Hello I have upgraded Webdriver manager from 4.3.1 to 5.2.1 and then my code isn’t working.

This is the code :
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().config().setChromeDriverVersion(driverVersion);

driverFile = new File(Global.WINDOWS_USER_HOME + "\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win32\" +WebDriverManager.chromedriver().config().getChromeDriverVersion() + "\chromedriver.exe");

Even though driver version is properly set WebDriverManager.chromedriver().config().getChromeDriverVersion()is coming a blank. It is working fine with 4.3.1. Is there any code update i have to make?? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As the [WebDriverManager doc](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) says:

> Each manager was a singleton object in older WebDriverManager releases
> (e.g., 4.x), while in version 5, a new manager instance is created
> each time. Therefore, the usage of `getDownloadedDriverPath()` and
> `getDownloadedDriverVersion()` can be different in WebDriverManager 5
> (i.e., these methods need to be invoked using a WebDriverManager
> instance previously created).

Therefore, maybe you need to reuse the same instance of WebDriverManager that you use in different statements, such as:

```
WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver();
wdm.setup();
String chromedriverPath = wdm.getDownloadedDriverPath();
```

Comment: EdgeDriver is not getting downloaded with same code. 

WebDriverManager.edgedriver().arch64().config().setEdgeDriverVersion(driverversion);